# C# Merge two datatable with different scheme and return hierarchical json

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, hierarchy

I have a DataTable which is dynamic and can have 5-10 columns. In the below example I am only showing 4 columns.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("America");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Japan");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Singapore");

            dataTable.Rows.Add("A", 200, 100, 300);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("B", 300, 300, 600);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("C", 400, 400, 700);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("D", 500, 500, 800);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("E", 600, 600, 900);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("F", 700, 700, 1000);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("G", 800, 800, 600);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("H", 900, 100, 400);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("I", 100, 200, 300);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("J", 200, 300, 200);
            dataTable.Rows.Add("K", 300, 500, 500);
```

This datatable is guaranteed have to `Name` column and other columns may or may not appear.

I have a mapping DataTable which also has `Name` column (which can be used to join two datatables) & it also has two more columns which establishes relation between rows.

```
 DataTable mappingTable = new DataTable();
            mappingTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            mappingTable.Columns.Add("id");
            mappingTable.Columns.Add("parentID");


            mappingTable.Rows.Add("A", 1, null);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("B", 2, 1);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("C", 3, 1);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("D", 4, null);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("E", 5, 4);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("F", 6, null);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("G", 7, 6);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("H", 8, 6);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("I", 9, 1);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("J", 10, null);
            mappingTable.Rows.Add("K", 11, 10);
```

Currently I am returning JSON from DataTable by using:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
```

and it produces following output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "america": "200",
    "japan": "100",
    "singapore": "300"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "america": "300",
    "japan": "300",
    "singapore": "600"
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "america": "400",
    "japan": "400",
    "singapore": "700"
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "america": "500",
    "japan": "500",
    "singapore": "800"
  },
  {
    "name": "E",
    "america": "600",
    "japan": "600",
    "singapore": "900"
  },
  {
    "name": "F",
    "america": "700",
    "japan": "700",
    "singapore": "1000"
  },
  {
    "name": "G",
    "america": "800",
    "japan": "800",
    "singapore": "600"
  },
  {
    "name": "H",
    "america": "900",
    "japan": "100",
    "singapore": "400"
  },
  {
    "name": "I",
    "america": "100",
    "japan": "200",
    "singapore": "300"
  },
  {
    "name": "J",
    "america": "200",
    "japan": "300",
    "singapore": "200"
  },
  {
    "name": "K",
    "america": "300",
    "japan": "500",
    "singapore": "500"
  }
]
```

But instead of returning this kind of JSON, I need to use Mapping DataTable and establish relation between rows and return a hierarchical JSON which looks like this:

```
[{
        "name": "A",
        "america": "200",
        "japan": "100",
        "singapore": "300",
        "children": [{
                "name": "B",
                "america": "300",
                "japan": "300",
                "singapore": "600"
            }, {
                "name": "C",
                "america": "400",
                "japan": "400",
                "singapore": "700"
            }, {
                "name": "I",
                "america": "100",
                "japan": "200",
                "singapore": "300"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "D",
        "america": "500",
        "japan": "500",
        "singapore": "800",
        "children": [{
                "name": "E",
                "america": "600",
                "japan": "600",
                "singapore": "900"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "F",
        "america": "700",
        "japan": "700",
        "singapore": "1000",
        "children": [{
                "name": "G",
                "america": "800",
                "japan": "800",
                "singapore": "600"
            }, {
                "name": "H",
                "america": "900",
                "japan": "100",
                "singapore": "400"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "J",
        "america": "200",
        "japan": "300",
        "singapore": "200",
        "children": [{
                "name": "K",
                "america": "300",
                "japan": "500",
                "singapore": "500"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The structure of DataTable can change as I may get more or less number of columns. How can I produce the required JSON output ?

Comment: sounds as you need to use some objects with lists/dictionaries. Load data from db into these objects instead of data table

Comment: Maybe you need another structure to represent your data. You can't use class because your records have dynamics structure. So I'm think that List of dictionary could help you. A person is represented by a dictionary of properties, where one of them is children property. Then you will need a logic to dump you data into it.

Comment: @T.S. The structure (no. of columns) was not fixed that is why i decided to use DataTable.

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger: What you said makes sense but this will mean I need to change lot of existing code. I will go that route only if I do not find any alternate solution.

Comment: Do the Ids used in the mapping table always match up with the row number in the first table?

Comment: @npearson: yes, they do match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an elegant way to do this using DataTable relations. If you can't get away from using DataTables you can manually map the data into the structure you need. This assumes the ids in the mapping table always match up with the row numbers in the data table.

```
var data = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c.ColumnName]))
    .ToList();
var mapping = mappingTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => !r["parentID"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
    .ToLookup(r => (int)r["parentID"], r => (int)r["id"]);

var output = new List<Dictionary<string, Object>>();
foreach (var group in mapping) {
    data[group.Key - 1].Add("children", group.Select(c => data[c - 1]).ToList());
    output.Add(data[group.Key - 1]);
}

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

Comment: Only change i had to make to make this work is add dataType to `MappingDataTable.  mappingTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeOf(string));
            mappingTable.Columns.Add("id", typeOf(int));
            mappingTable.Columns.Add("parentID", typeOf(int));`